# Is it possible to create Azure SQL Database master master replication

Tags: sql, azure

I am sorry because I'm new to use Azure service.
I want two SQL databases (one in Southeast Asia and one in Central US) for high availability or replication master-master.

Now I just found two ways to sync both databases.

1. Azure Geo-Replication
   but the problem is this method use master-slave replication.
2. Azure Sync to other databases
   but the sync frequency is 5 minutes, not realtime.

Please advise me or give me a reference, what the service that I should use to make master-master replication on Azure SQL databases?

Comment: what's  the kind of  your Azure SQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is tagged MySQL so I'll assume you're referring to the Azure MySQL PaaS offering.

Azure Database for MySQL does not currently support scaling out of write workloads; All slave databases are read-only.

You are wanting to achieve high availability: I would check what HA options are available in your front-end CRM and if possible then provision one instance in Central US and one in Southeast Asia.  You could then use other HA infrastructure, and perhaps some monitoring & automation, to route requests to the CRM accordingly.  You can get some tips from this multi-region SQL HA reference architecture:

[Run an N-tier application in multiple Azure regions for high availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/n-tier/multi-region-sql-server)

Hope this helps.